# DateFormat DateTime Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a strange issue with my project:

While using the same MSSQL Database, my local version shows date like this:

[image]

And my web version shows like this:

[image]

Moreover, when I'm trying to edit, in my local version the "datepicker" is populated by my model.date, and on the web version.. not.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })\
```

Here's part of viewmodel:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayName("Data od")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

I assume its because of that different Date format. How can I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new Data Annotation to StartDate property

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```